# Ubuntu password policy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, password, pam

I want to set the system-wide password policy on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server. Googling around, a lot of people point to this (very old) document:

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/user-management.html

It says to edit the `/etc/pam.d/common-password` file and look for the `password required` line:

```
password    required    pam_unix.so nullok obscure min=6 max=8 md5
```

To set the minimum password length, adjust the `min=` setting.

However, on 12.04, my file looks like this (comments removed):

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512
password    requisite           pam_deny.so
password    required            pam_permit.so
```

Which line do I change? The one with `pam_unix.so`? Or the one with `password required`? Or is it now in some other file? There's nothing in that file's comments about setting the password policies.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the first line `password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512`

But don't use md5 since the new one is using sha512. If you want to set a minimum password length (8) use the line below

```
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512 min=8
```

Answer (score 4):

[`pam_unix`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_unix.html) is the [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) module that handles authentication with a user name and password, so that's where you would configure a password policy.

In the [PAM configuration](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-configuration-file.html), the first column indicates the management group. Here, it's `password`, which configures updates of users' authentication data. The second column specifies the control flow between the different modules, don't touch it unless you know what you're doing. The third column is the module name and the subsequent columns are parameters to this module.

Look in the [`pam_unix` documentation](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_unix.html), or better in the `pam_unix` man page on your system, to see what options are supported. Add the options you want, e.g.

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512 rounds=10000 minlen=8
```

You might want to add other modules to perform complexity checks on the password, such as [`pam_cracklib`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_cracklib.html). Set `pam_cracklib` as `required` and put it before `pam_unix` (which validates the password change):

```
password    required                    pam_cracklib.so retry=3 difok=1 minlen=10
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512 rounds=10000 minlen=8
```